# JQuery set display property based on array contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to take an old piece of JavaScript code that I have and turn it into JQuery but I can't seem to get it right any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
var termarray = ["help", "help me", "-h", "--help"];
commandterm = $("#search-bar").val();

document.getElementById('helpblock').style.display = ~termarray.indexOf(commandterm.toLowerCase()) ? "block" : "none";
```

This is what I currently have in JavaScript.

EDIT 1:

I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. This is the OLD JavaScript code

```
document.getElementById('helpblock').style.display = ~termarray.indexOf(commandterm.toLowerCase()) ? "block" : "none";
```

What I am trying to do is take this and make it JQuery. What it is supposed to do is basically summed up like this:

If termarray contains commandterm then set helpblock display to block, if not then set it to none.

I can achieve this with an If Statement but I feel it isn't overly efficient as I will be writing a few of these lines for text detection.

As for a JQuery alternative I am not entirely sure where to start after the equals so for now I have:

```
$('#kws').css('display') =
```

Beyond that, I am not really sure... My apologies for the lack of description.

Comment: show your example by using code snippet. Then it'll be clear for us to understand what you actually want to do

Comment: Please share what was your old code and what you have changed in it. Also what is the error that is coming.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var termarray = ["help", "help me", "-h", "--help"];
console.log(~termarray.indexOf("help"));
console.log(~termarray.indexOf("help") ? "block" : "none");
console.log(~termarray.indexOf("-m"));
console.log(~termarray.indexOf("-m") ? "block" : "none");
```

Your logic is working properly.

Check if you are selecting proper element while displaying `document.getElementById('helpblock').style.display`

and `$("#search-bar").val();` is returning proper value or not.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my edit, I didn't explain what I was trying to do properly. The code I have in Javascript is working however I would like to convert it to JQuery. Thank you for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `display` to `block` if the `commandterm` exists in array then compare `indexOf` to -1

```
document.getElementById('helpblock').style.display = termarray.indexOf(commandterm.toLowerCase())!=-1 ? "block" : "none";
```

**-1 is not considered as false**

Check this demo below:

```js
var x = "a";
x = ["somestring"].indexOf("someotherstring") ? "exists" : "doesnotexists";
console.log(x);
```

Comment: doesn't matter .. it will take -1 as false and rest as true.

Comment: @AtulSharma -1 is not considered as false

Comment: @AtulSharma try running the demo I have in my code. :)

Comment: `["somestring"].indexOf("somestring") ? "exists" : "doesnotexists";` output is `doesnotexists`. I think js is thinking little opposite :P

Comment: It is logical, because in your array, indexOf returns 0 which is the index of `somestring ` element. But as 0 is treated as false so it equating to doesnotexists. **So it is always a good practice to compare indexOf to -1 always**

Answer (score 0):

```
var termarray = ["help", "help me", "-h", "--help"];
commandterm = $("#search-bar").val();
var displayType ;
var indexOfArray = jQuery.inArray(commandterm, termarray);
if (indexOfArray == -1) {
   displayType = "none"
} else {
   displayType = "block";
}

$("#helpblock").css("display",displayType);
```